# Triangles and Congruency

Tags: triangles

1.) If two angles of one triangle are congruent to two angles of another triangle, then the triangles are congruent.

Is that SOMETIMES TRUE, ALWAYS TRUE, OR NEVER TRUE?
I know that it is not NEVER TRUE.

2.) Two equilateral triangles with a pair of congruent corresponding sides are congruent.

Is that SOMETIMES TRUE, ALWAYS TRUE, OR NEVER TRUE?
I mean I know that it is not NEVER TRUE.

3.) Imagine that you have a isosceles triangle. The triangle name is KMN. Angle K and Angle M are base angles and N is a vertex angle. Angle N is bisected by line NL. L is the midpoint of KM. I know that KLN is not congruent to LMN, but what do we need to know for the two triangles to be congruent? What method, like SSS or ASA?

4.) Imagine that you have a parallelogram ABCD. AD is parallel to BC? What do we need to prove ADC is congruent to BAC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question  because you show no work of your own. You have asked several questions on this site so you should know by now that you should ask just one question per post, and show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1) SOMETIMES TRUE

2) ALWAYS TRUE

3) SSS

4) That the parallelogram is a rectangle

Comment: Regarding 1) couldn’t the triangles be similar but not congruent ?

Comment: 1) is not always true.  The triangles could be similar triangles